# What was the average income from ebooks for independent authors in 2013?

Tags: publishing, independent-publishing

Ebooks have been a boon to independent authors, providing a path to audiences, unmatched in the history of publishing.  The field is rather new, and currently there is not even Wikipedia page [Independent author](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_author).

If possible what is the number of Independent authors who published English language works in 2013, and what was the average incoming from those 2013 works?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Statista](http://www.statista.com/) (The Statistics Portal) looks like it has some relevant [ebooks revenue information](http://www.statista.com/search/?q=ebooks%20revenue) (though not exactly what you are looking for). Unfortunately, you are forced to sign up for a premium account to access most of the reports. A sample report that they actually show you *some* of the information for is [here](http://www.statista.com/statistics/280249/global-e-book-revenue-by-region/) (`Global e-book revenue from 2009 to 2016*, by region (in million U.S. dollars)`, obviously some is projection).

I did manage to find an informal survey done by [Marie Force](https://www.blogger.com/profile/00550719567520289405) about independent publishers [here](http://e-bookformattingfairies.blogspot.ca/2013/04/author-know-thy-business-self.html) (covers total unit sales broken down between 2010, 2011, 2012 and some of 2013) . Here is an excerpt:

> The conversation on the loop led to me post an informal survey to get
>   an idea of how our members and their self-publishing friends are
>   really doing. I didn't ask people to give dollar amounts, but rather
>   just their number of sales in 2010, 2011, 2012 and so far in 2013. I
>   asked them to list their most successful book in 2012 and how many
>   copies it sold. At the outset, I want to say that this survey was
>   informal. There is nothing scientific about it, but it does provide an
>   interesting snapshot of how self-published authors are really doing.
>
> To give context to the numbers, I wanted to also provide a guide to
>   what the most popular price points translate to in actual dollars.
>   Using Amazon's conversion chart, here it is:
>
> 0.99 (35 percent royalty): $0.35 per sale
>   1.99 (35 percent royalty): $0.70 per sale
>   2.99 (70 percent royalty): $2.04 per sale
>   3.99 (70 percent royalty): $2.74 per sale
>   4.99 (70 percent royalty): $3.44 per sale
>
> While I didn't ask authors to list their most common price point
>   (which I will add to the survey next time), I thought the breakdown
>   above would be enlightening to the authors out there who might be
>   waffling about whether they ought to try their hand at
>   self-publishing. If you are thinking about whether or not you should
>   dip your toe into the revolutionary waters, ask yourself these
>   questions: When was the last time I made $3.44 on the sale of one
>   book? When was the last time I made even $2.04 on the sale of one
>   book?

She then goes on to post a bunch of survey results broken down by author. Here is a sample of one of the survey results:

> Elisabeth Naughton
>  Romantic Suspense and Paranormal 
> Total number of
>   self-published titles: 12 
> Total number of self-published sales in
>   2010: 0 
> Total number of self-published sales in 2011: 0 
> Total number
>   of self-published sales in 2012: 102,179 
> Total number of
>   self-published sales so far in 2013: Jan-March 2013: 370,059 
> Most
>   successful book in 2012 and how many sold: MARKED - 30,673 copies
>
> I've been traditionally published for four years and my income comes
>   primarily from my self-published titles, NOT my traditionally
>   published titles.